# How do I change the Date module to get 'days back and forward'?

Tags: datetime

I want to restrict the dates a user can select when using past dates. I want a pop-up message when he tries to select a day +1 month from current date.

How can I do this? Do I need to override the module? If so, how?

Comment: Is this Drupal 6 or 7?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add a new form validation handler. To avoid any conflict with the existing validation handler, you should probably remove the existing one added from the Date module, if there is one.